# inline SVG clipPath on multiple elements

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, safari

I'm trying to use the same SVG clipPath on multiple image elements.

It works fine in FF and Chrome, but when I try to run this code in Safari it breaks after the first image. And in Internet Explorer 10+ it does not seem to work at all

**How can I make this work in safari and IE10+ as well?**

```css
.clip {
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#myclippath");
  clip-path: url("#myclippath");
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="clip" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" />

<img class="clip" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" />

<img class="clip" src="https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/images/modules/logos_page/Octocat.png" />


    <svg>
          <defs>
                <clipPath id="myclippath" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                      <polygon points="0 0, 0.38 0, 0.50 0.4, 0.62 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1" />
                </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: You can't clip an HTML `<img>` in IE, if you convert the images to SVG `<image>` elements you'll be able to clip them.

Comment: Do you know if I can make the <image> element 100% with height of parent element?

Comment: height="100%" width="100%"